# Return Object, Object

Tags: reactjs, object, return

I have the following React code:

```
const ResultItem = ({ category, name }) =>

  <div className="projects animated fadeInUp">
       <a href ={"/projects " + {name}}> 
       <h1 style ={project_box_h1}> {name} </h1></a>
    <div className={`category--${category}`} />
  </div>;
```

In `h1` variable `{name}` is working correctly and returns `"Name"`.

But, in `a href` variable `{name}` returns something like this:

```
http://localhost:1234/projects%20[object%20Object]
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href ={"/projects " + name}>
```

or

```
<a href ={`/projects ${name}`}>
```